# How do I get rid of italicized letters when using $$?

Tags: math-mode, italic

Let's say I want to type:

> Hi, my name is {Mika}

When I use `$$` on both sides:

```
$$ Hi, my name is {Mika} $$
```

It would be italicize and the brackets {} would go away. How can I prevent that?

Comment: `$$ <...> $$` is Plain-TeX syntax for display math mode (hence the italics). What are you trying to achieve with `$$`?

Comment: Load `amsmath` and use `\[ \text{Hi, my name is \{Mika\}} \]`. Do not use `$$`...`$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can prevent that by not using `$$` on both sides ;-)

Comment: If you wish to italicize text, then using the math mode is absolutely wrong. Just go for `\textit{Hi, my name is \{John Doe\}}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{` and `}` are special. You need to escape them to use them properly - `\{` and `\}`. And, for the setting you seem to be attempting, it may be better to use the `center` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  Hi, my name is \{John Doe\}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```